# Can the auction house notify you in game?

Tags: diablo-iii

Is there an option to have the auction house message you when you are in game whenever an item sells?

Basically enabling the message it sends when you are on the menus or party screen and something sells.

Comment: Question should be close as there is no longer an auction house for diablo 3.

Comment: @z- Question should not be closed. See [this answer](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/8451/50582) to your own meta question about D3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of the 1.05 patch, there is now an option on the Social tab to have Auction House events show up in the chat log.  This includes all the things that you would get as toasts when not in a game, such as being outbid, having an item sell, winning an auction, etc.

Answer (score 3):

This is [not possible](https://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5149539655), but it seems to be a heavily requested feature.

Comment: Probably something they will add once they activate the RMAH. If you are bidding with real money that Blizzard gets a cut of, surely they want to let you know when you're outbid so you can increase your bid! ;)

Comment: I wish we just had mailboxes to get stuff from the AH, like we do in WoW. Its rather tedious to join/leave a game to interact with the AH